# Api GetAccessToken in C# not return

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-5

I used the following code to get a token value but error (The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.)   returns Thanks for the guidance.

```
      private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
       using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
           const string URL = "https://bime.net.iraneit.com:3023/BimeApiManager_Main/api/EITAuthentication/GetAppToken";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, String>> postData = new Dictionary<String, String>();

            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("appname", "   "));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>("secret", "  "));
            FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

            var ttt = content;
            var result = await client.PostAsync(URL, content);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("appToken", content);


            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string JString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                object responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JString);
                return ((dynamic)responseData).access_token;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: What API are you using?  Looks like a WebClient!!!  If you have a work application use a sniffer and compare first request headers in working to non working.  
Then modify c# header look like working application.  The default headers in Net are not the same as other web methods and the headers need to be changed.

Comment: How are you calling `GetAccessToken`?